# Unable to return address array in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, addresses, arrays, payable

I have the following code for a simple gambling game.
The code works fine except for **getPlayers** function

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

contract Lottery {
address payable public manager;
address payable [] public players; 

constructor () public {
    manager = msg.sender;
}
function enter() public payable {

    require(msg.value > 0.01 ether); //condition
    players.push(msg.sender);
}

function random() private view returns(uint) {
    return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, now, 
players)));
}

function pickWinner() public restricted{
    uint index = random() % players.length;
    players[index].transfer(address(this).balance);
    players = new address payable[](0); // new dynamic array

}

modifier restricted() {
    require(msg.sender == manager); // security
    _;
}

function getPlayers() public payable returns (address[] memory) {
    return players;
    // Error in the above line saying
    // "Return argument type address payable[] storage ref is not implicitly convertible to expected type(type of first return variable)  address[] memory."

}
}
```

Comment: "The code works fine" - impossible. This is a compilation error, which means that you couldn't have possibly tested the code as of yet.

Comment: You can fix this error by removing the `memory` keyword that you've placed in the declaration of function `getPlayers`. Side note: since `players` is a public state variable, the compiler automatically creates a getter function for this variable, which you can invoke from the off-chain via `players()`. So this function seems redundant, and you may as well get rid of it altogether.

Comment: By the way, I gotta admit I've never seen the use of `payable` in the declaration of variables (as you do at the beginning of your contract).

Comment: @goodvibration Yes, the recent Solidity versions have added the `address payable` type to the language.

Comment: @goodvibration i can't use players() to get the entire array of address since they are payable. The function requires an internal parameter that points to the index of the array.

Yes, as of 0.5.0 version, any address that transacts ether has to be predeclared as payable and same is the case for any callback function.

Comment: @goodvibration i have to use "memory" for address type as the editor is prompting me for that.This is a change in solidity 0.5.0

Comment: how to pass these players address payable[] public players;
to modifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few problems here.

I'm not sure where `pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;` originates but it's picked up by a lot of people and appears in many examples. The problem is there are too many breaking changes in successive compiler versions for it to be right very often. *In my opinion* it's always better to specify exactly which compiler the code is written for.

I realize it's not your question, but the `enter()` function is set up to swallow funds with no means of retrieval. No accounting is being done and no check for excessive amounts (error). At a minimum, require the precise amount and reject user errors.

```
require(msg.value = ticketPrice);
```

The players function is returning the full array. This is an anti-pattern because it will stop working when it exceeds the block gasLimit. It should not be necessary to implement such a function.

First, emit an event in the `enter()` function to inform observers there has been a state change. This makes it reasonable to assume that any interested party already has the complete list of players.

`event LogNewPlayer(address newPlayer);`

...

`emit LogNewPlayer(playerAddress);`

Second, make the state discoverable at a fixed cost per transaction, independent of scale. Iteration should be a client-side concern. Provided the individual transactions always complete at a reasonable cost, a client can iterate endlessly. Better to have lots of cheap operations that one costly operation.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract Lottery {

    address payable[] public players;

    // above is just enough wrapper to compiler and test these.

    function getPlayerAtIndex(uint index) public view returns(address player) {
        return players[index];
    }

    function getPlayerCount() public view returns(uint count) {
        return players.length;
    }
}
```

The address array is `storage` but the `returns` of a function have to be memory. That means iterating over the stored list and copying all of that data to memory.

A more permissive compiler might make that seem like an okay thing to do. In Solidity 5.x I believe you would have to explicitly handle the conversion so it's clear you are conscious of what you're doing. It would be awful owing to the scalability concerns. Something like:

```
function grossDoNotUse() public view returns(address[] memory) {
    address[] memory playerList;
    for(uint i=0; i<getPlayerCount(); i++) {
        playerList[i] = players[i];
    }
    return playerList;
}
```

Don't do that!

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am just a beginner in this and all the explanation above was a bit over my head! I'll be extrmely greatful if you could tell me how can i overcome the error im getting above.

since im just working on a testing network using ganach, I dont see an issue with gas limit **for now** . However I have a note of it when i proceed with the logic at a later stage.
Thank you

Comment: `grossDoNotUse()` address your issue with `getPlayers()` without changing the approach. Since you're just starting out, that should be fine. Rename it and replace your implementation.

Comment: The two functions laid out earlier get around the dangers slightly altering your approach. Instead of expecting a whole list, you will get one entry at a time as you ask for them (by row). You can find a fuller explanation here: https://blog.b9lab.com/getting-loopy-with-solidity-1d51794622ad

Comment: i clearly got your approach @Rob, thanks a lot.
However the function above is still not working. It's giving me **invalid opcode** error . Function is returning an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

The original poster was almost definitely working on an exercise from the book, or Udemy course, "Ethereum and Solidity: The Complete Developer's Guide". The course is quite outdated by now and most users will struggle to test the examples in Remix using the examples provided.

I'm working through the course myself and found this repo very useful: https://github.com/harmony-one/dapp-examples/blob/master/nodejs/contracts/lottery/Lottery.sol

That said, yes, the course is introductory and doesn't address any of the real world complexities that Rob addresses, but, if you stumble here like I did, check the repo above or just try ...

`function getPlayers() public view returns (address payable[] memory) { return players; }`

then when you finish the course, go back and ready the first response. :)

Answer (score 0):

As of version 0.5.0 Solidity has two address types: `address` and `address payable`.

The problem is that they cannot be implicitly converted when in memory array form, but you are trying to assign a `address payable storage[]` to a `address memory[]`.

You can solve this by changing the return type of `getPlayers` to `address payable memory[]`

Comment: i tried your suggestion but im getting an ParserError on Remix.
Error says " Expected ',' but got '[' "

Its not accepting a payable return type

Comment: Here is the changed function definition

/*
    function getPlayers() public payable returns (address[] payable memory) {
        return players;
        }
*/

Comment: @AnukoolSrivastava The correct declaration should be `function getPlayers() public view returns (address payable[] memory) {`

Comment: tried that, but in my local editor 'visual studio code' im getting an error with this 
`address payable public manager;*`

it gives me an error saying **expected identifier but got 'payable'**

the code is running perfectly fine on remix but when im trying to plug it with reactjs project, im getting the above error

Comment: @AnukoolSrivastava Then you are compiling with a Solidity version lower than `0.5.0`. To use `address payable` you need at least version `0.5.0`

Comment: That part is corrected. However the main issue i had in the beginning still remains.
I need an entire list of players in an array altogether, and im getting different errors