# Storage arrays don't store my input values

Tags: truffle, ganache, truffle-test

I checked other similar topics but I still can't figure out how to solve my problem, the code below is part of my contract,

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract MyContract{
    address owner;

    mapping (address => bool) isManagerAddress;
    mapping (address => Organization) charityAddressInfos;
    mapping (address => bool) isValidated;
    address payable[] charityAddresses;
    address[] managerAddresses;

    uint256 totalDonationsAmount;
    uint256 highestDonation;
    address highestDonor;

    enum OrganizationType{
        Education, //0
        Health, //1
        Environment, //2
        Religion, //3
        CivilSociety, //4
        International, //5
        BigInternational, //6
        GovernmentOrganized //7
    }

struct Organization{
        string organizationName;
        OrganizationType[] organizationTypes;
    }

.
.
.
//
function addNewOrganization(string memory organizationName, OrganizationType[] memory organizationTypes) external {

        Organization storage newOrganization = charityAddressInfos[msg.sender];

        newOrganization.organizationName = organizationName;
        newOrganization.organizationTypes = organizationTypes;

        charityAddresses.push(payable(msg.sender));
        charityAddressInfos[msg.sender] = newOrganization;
    }

function getAddresses() public view returns (address payable[] memory) {
    return charityAddresses;
}
//
.
.
.

}
```

And I am trying to test this function

```
it('Add new org', async () => {
            const instance = await Charity.deployed();

            await instance.addNewOrganization('Unicef', [0, 3, 5]);

             console.log(await instance.getAddresses());

        });
```

The test works well and I can see the outcome in the console but my problem is, I can't see my input values in ganache after the test is done , or when I call getAddresses() the array looks empty

I lost so much time with this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Returning the entire array is an anti-pattern.  See this issue: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/64101/unable-to-return-address-array-in-solidity.  for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay that's not about the code, I just have thought I could see state variable or array changes in ganache interface when I update them but I found out ganache reverts states after the test.

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/4659